# Не отправляется эмбед с кнопками

Tags: python, бот, button, discord.py

Хотел сделать отправку эмбеда с кнопками, однако само сообщение по коду удаляется, а эмбед с кнопками не показывается.

```
@client.command()
@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
async def ticket(ctx):
    await ctx.message.delete()

    embed = discord.Embed(title ='Тикеты', description = 'Добро пожаловать в систему тикетов.', colour = discord.Colour.gold()) 

    await ctx.send(
        embed = embed,
        components = [
            Button(
                custom_id = 'Ticket',
                label = "Создать тикет",
                style = ButtonStyle.green,
                emoji ='')
        ]
    )
```

Comment: А что происходит? Эмбед без конопок? вообще нет ембеда?

Comment: Сообщение с командой "!ticket" удаляется по коду, а после - ноль реакции, то есть эмбед даже не отправляется.